# How to check if the register has a even value?

Tags: assembly, arm

For example , check if R8 is even

This is given answer

```
MOVS R2,R8,LSR#1
```

shift LSB to carry flag if =0>even  if =1 >odd

I dont get this part.

For example decimal value 7 in ARM is 0..0 0111 , shifting right by 1 we get 0..0 0011. The carry here means the right most bit ?

Another way will be checking if the right most bit is 1 or 0 using mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base 2 number is even (divisible by 2) if the low bit is 0.  For exactly the same reason a base 10 number is divisible by 10 if the low digit is 0.

---

Shifts put the last bit shifted out into the C flag, so you can tell if `R8` is even by looking at the C flag.  As [ARM documentation says](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204f/Cihcdehh.html):

> If S is specified, these instructions update the N and Z flags
>   according to the result.
>
> The C flag is unaffected if the shift value is 0. **Otherwise, the C
>   flag is updated to the last bit shifted out.**

But yes, the normal way to test for odd/even is [`tst r8, #1`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204f/Cihcdehh.html) to set the Z flag according to the low bit.  So `beq r8_was_even` or `bne r8_was_odd`, or whatever else you want to do with the Z flag.

If you have a use for the right-shifted integer result (or its zero/non-zero status in `Z`), `movs` with a shift (aka `lsrs`) is an efficient way to get both the `x/2` and `x&1` results at once.

Comment: Thank you . Are we  using 'tst'   to set the zero flag? if zero flag is set , it will be even else odd?

Comment: @XiangRuiLiu: I updated my answer but forgot to ping you.  The `eq` and `ne` conditions read the Z flag.